# Erro no CSS dos plugins do WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou com o seguinte problema, meu tema no WordPress não reconhece o CSS dos plugins instalados nas páginas internas, na *home* funciona normalmente, mas nas outras páginas, nenhum plugin que eu instalo reconhece o CSS.

Alguém pode em ajudar?

Comment: Tens `<?php wp_head(); ?>` no teu ficheiro `header.php` ?

Comment: Nossa era isso mesmo, estava faltando. Obrigado já resolveu meu problema Zuul. Abs!

Answer (score 3):

Provávelmente o teu problema será a falta da função [`wp_head()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) no teu ficheiro `header.php` ou `index.php` cuja mesma é geralmente utilizada com gancho para carregar estilos, scripts e meta tags:

```php
<?php 
 ...
    /* Aplicar sempre a função wp_head() imediatamente antes da tag de fecho </head>
     * no teu tema, ou vai-se quebrar muitos plugins, que geralmente usam este gancho 
     * para adicionar elementos na <head>, tais como estilos, scripts e meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
 ?>
 </head>
```

**Nota:**

Em algums casos, o problema reside também na ausência da função [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) no ficheiro `footer.php` ou `index.php` cuja mesma pode estar a servir de gancho para referênciar ficheiros de JavaScript:

```php
...
<?php
   /* Aplicar sempre a função wp_footer() imediatamente antes da tag de fecho </body>
    * no teu tema, ou vai-se quebrar muitos plugins, que geralmente usam
    * este gancho para adicionar ficheiros de JavaScript.
    */
    wp_footer();
?>
</body>
</html>
```